# RE MEDICAL SEO and web building

Tags: seo, html, wordpress, php

From an SEO Point of view, what is better for a medical or dental website? PHP, HTML or Wordpress and why? My SEO person said php is read better by google bots - Somebody verify....thanks

Comment: John, while it is opinion based, the underlying understanding is wrong, so is good to leave open to allow other answers

Answer (score 2):

Get yourself a new SEO person.

By the time it reaches a browser, there is nothing except the script extension of .php to indicate that the page is not pure HTML.  In fact, it could even be a .php page and not use any PHP scripting.

PHP is used to generate HTML and that is what is served to a site viewer.

Given that WordPress is a pure PHP site their answer doesn't make any sense at all.